# SQL Select LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have an SQL table that is of this format.

```
items
Field       Type        Null    Key Default Extra   
id          int(11)     NO      PRI NULL    auto_increment
name        varchar(30) NO          NULL    
categories  varchar(255)NO          NULL
```

And I'm filling the table with values such as this:

```
id: 1, name: "Object", categories: 1, 4, 5
id: 2, name: "Object 2", categories: 10, 14, 19
```

So the idea is that each object can have as many categories as it wants.

If I run this query to get every object from category 1

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `categories` LIKE '%1%';
```

It returns both of the objects, even though I really only want the first object, because it's specifically in category 1.

Is there any way to get around this, or should I create a new table in which each row is a unique category for each object?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you probably should do that thing with creating another table (it is called normalization).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default table design for such a *n to m* relation is

```
items table
-----------
id
name
...


categories table
----------------
id
name
...


item_categories table
---------------------
item_id
category_id
```

If you then want to select all items for a specific category you can do

```
select i.*
from items i
join item_categories ic on ic.item_id = i.id
join categories c on ic.category_id = c.id
where c.name = 'my category 1'
```